# Reading from stdin OR file using awk

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk

So here's my code so far:

```
awk '{++a[length()]} END{for (i in a) print i, a[i]}' <$1 | sort -n
```

which reads the lengths of lines from a text file, and outputs the length of the line, and then how many lines have the same length.

So input:

```
hello
guys
hows
it
going
```

Will output:

```
2 1
4 2
5 2
```

I want it to be able to have stdin too, so i will be able to run the command "./script filename.txt" and also be able to run the command using standard input.

Is there any way this can be done with a while loop? I have tried to do something similar to:

```
while read line
do
    awk '{++a[length()]} END{for (i in a) print i, a[i]}' <${1:-/dev/stdin} | sort -n
done <${1:-/dev/stdin}
```

but nothing seems to be working correctly...

Any ideas?

Comment: If you told us what instead of how and posted sample data along with the expected output we might be able to help you. If you want to solve it by yourself and want to read from stdin and a file with awk at the same time, use `getline` for the file. Good luck.

Comment: What are you talking about? You are already reading from stdin!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You may use the dash (`-`) as the filename, awk understands it as using stdin as the file to parse. For example:

```
awk '{++a[length()]} END{for (i in a) print i, a[i]}' -
```

Also, by not specifying a filename at all, awk also uses stdin

```
awk '{++a[length()]} END{for (i in a) print i, a[i]}'
```

And note that you can mix them both. The following will process file1.txt, stdin and file2.txt in that order:

```
awk '{++a[length()]} END{for (i in a) print i, a[i]}' file1.txt - file2.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

awk can read by default by stdin when you pipe data to awk.

You can read data from both file and stdin like this:

```
echo $'pipe1\npipe2\npipe3' | awk '{print NR, $0}' file -
```

The dash in the end represent stdin.